# How do I not get Run-time error '13': Type mismatch while iterating rows?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to go through a column and increment each value by one until it's empty but I get a run time error:

> Run-time error '13': Type mismatch

Please help.

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Start = Val(Range("H2").Value)
    LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 8).End(xlUp).Row

    For Row = 2 To LastRow
        If Not IsEmpty(Range("H" & Row)) Then
            Range("H" & Row).Value = Range("H" & Row).Value + 1
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: On which line do you get the error?

Comment: You will want to test whether the cell contains a number.  If you try to add 1 to text it will fail.

Comment: If the cell contains a string or an error value, you can expect a mismatch here.

Comment: I get the error on Range("H" & Row).Value = Range("H" & Row).Value + 1.

Comment: How would you handle the error here? I want it to stop when the cell is empty and don't show me the error.

Comment: `IsEmpty` doesn't care for cells, it works off `Variant` and returns `True` when the variant subtype is `Empty` - which happens to be the case for a cell that doesn't contain *anything* - no formula, no value, no empty string, nothing. Can you confirm that this is that what you're looking for? Also where is `Row` defined? Put `Option Explicit` at the top of the module, and always declare all your variables.

Comment: I want to check if there is a number in the cell, increment by one, if there is not a number, do nothing.

Answer (score 2):

Here's some untested code that should isoluate your issue. The way you set your range up is a little strange. Give this a try.

```
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet 'i assume this is correct

Dim r As Long
Dim cNumber As Long
cNumber = Range("h2").Column 'just for illustration

For r = 2 To ws.UsedRange.Cells(ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count, 1).Row


    If Not IsEmpty(ws.Cells(r, cNumber)) Then

        If IsNumeric(ws.Cells(r, cNumber)) Then
            ws.Cells(r, cNumber).Value = ws.Cells(r, cNumber).Value + 1
        Else
            'cell is not empty but does not have a numeric value
            'Stop
        End If

    Else
            Exit For 'ends the loop


    End If

Next r
```

Comment: It doesn't work and but thanks for your time. In the meantime, is it possible for you to help me with my own code? I'd like to know what I'm doing wrong there so I can learn.

Comment: I just tested it on a spreadsheet with random numbers in column H. It does work. If you'd like to ask another question, feel free, but this solution does address your question of looping through a range, stopping on an empty value, not showing an error if not a number... and incrementing by 1. Test it on any spreadsheet with numbers in column H.

Comment: Open a new excel template. Put a formula of =ROW()  in cells `H2:H10`. Run the code I shared... all numbers will go up by 1.

Comment: Your `Start` code makes no sense, so it's ommitted. The rest is just the same as what you're doing of looping through column H.

Comment: @MehdiJafarnia "it didn't work" isn't helping anyone figuring out what the problem is with this [obviously correct and definitely more robust] code (although `.End(xlUp)` is more reliable). Instead of lashing out at people that *voluntarily* spend their time trying to help you *for free* to the best of their knowledge, consider whether maybe there's a possibility that your requirements are perhaps a bit confusing and under-specified, since mind-reading isn't something everyone can do? Lastly, please have a quick read at the site's [code of conduct](https://stackoverflow.com/conduct).

Comment: @MathieuGuindon `.end(Xlup)` will skip hidden rows, even if they have values. The used range approach may overshoot the last row, but since `Captain Friendly` wants to end when the cell is blank, going too far is harmless. `Find` is probably the most robust, but I wasn't sure I would get the exact syntax correct when typing on the fly. Thanks again for the click.